Framing board removal from attic
In our attic we have a a set of 3 attic trusses on each side.  In-between these trusses are horizontal boards that are just nailed in.  I am wondering if I could remove 1 of these horizontal boards without messing up the framing.
I've talked to a couple of contractors helping finish the attic (electrican, hvac, dry wall installers), and they all believe that this is not a structural piece of framing.
If you look at the first image, I would like to remove the 2nd horizontal board from the floor.  In the 2nd image it's the 3rd horizontal board from the floor.
The second image is to help capture the rest of the attic.  For example, right across from this area is the stairwell.
End goal is to make this area either extra storage or a nook-like spot.



From what I see, the attic is framed for drywall finishing, the last pic, put that into perspective. The removal of that 1 piece should cause no concern.
The horizontal framing in that area was added only to carry the sheetrock across that span. There are important structural members above the drywall framing to carry the roof sheathing.
The framing above the flat 2X4s is the framing that absolutely must stay, but you do not intend to go there anyway.

Just to make sure I'm understanding what you're saying:
You're saying that the horizontal boards that are just nailed into place, and that would be flush to any drywall attached to them I could simply just remove with no issues (to the detriment of any drywall work), but the boards that are more or less deeper into the framing that are not just nailed in, and are right under the plywood I should not remove.
Am I capturing everything correctly?

To affirm, yes at the sloped part of the ceiling/roof, which was not part of the question, but is part of the framing in that area. You were asking about the single horizontal piece you want to remove, which from what I see, is only to carry drywall, seeing the whole room, in the picture. Same with the 2X flat at the roof line, but those are only ones that do. The 2X6 that meet the roof plywood are critical and MUST remain. I only added that comment because there is a difference between framing members and their orientation. I try to detail too much and it tends to confuse. My apologies.

I believe the reason for the horizontal boards is to give lateral support between the trusses because the gap is larger.
If you remove the board, build a box with 3/4 plywood top,bottom and back to be your nook, that should more than replace the lateral weakness from removing the board.
